# Changing Datatables CSS functionality

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm having trouble figuring out how to work with the Datatables plugin for jQuery in the fact that I need for example if there are 3 numbered page links which would have the First, Previous, Next, Last links as well. If you were on page 1 then the First, Previous buttons should only have the pagination_button_disabled css applied to it but instead it ALSO has the paginate button and then the first or previous css style as well. I just want the first and last to have a css style of paginate_button_disabled if you are on page 1 and obviously revered if you were on page 3 then Last and Next should be disabled.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is already core functionality of DataTables. Are you sure you imported the structural css file for DataTables? `jquery.dataTables.css`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that even if they have the class 'paginate_button_disabled' no CSS for that class is defined (in fact all the CSS is inherited from the class 'paging_full_numbers'). I think you should define a css rule

```
.paging_full_numbers  .paginate_button_disabled{
    //put your rule for disabled content here
    color: gray;
}
```

after you load datatables CSS

EDIT - i edited your fiddle (only thing i modified is i loaded the source for datatables from the datatables.net site because the link of your script was broken).

I added this line of css

```
.dataTables_paginate .paginate_button_disabled{
     display:none;   
}
```

and the disabled button are hidden. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/F7GLm/2/

Comment: I already have my class of paginate_button_disabled setup with those rules and its still not doing it.  kansasoutlawwrestling.com/manager/css/style.css

Comment: Can you post your code (css, html and javascript?) (even better if you create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net). What version of datatables are you using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F7GLm/   however for some reason its not displaying it with 1 row per page. But it does in my CMS.

Comment: I edited your fiddle, it wasn't loading the js script of datatable because the path was local to your server. this works: http://jsfiddle.net/F7GLm/2/

Comment: What I"m actually attempting to do is this:  http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/manager/index2.html Notice how the disabled prev button is greyed out.

Comment: That didn't work. The disabled should be the same as the greyed out on the prev button on the template.

Comment: Like this (the color is the same and no effect on hover) http://jsfiddle.net/F7GLm/4/

Comment: I'm looking at it and looking at my template and they look nothing alike. All I see is the text. of the button.

Comment: I see why. Its because if I click on the First button it has first, paginate_button, and paginate_button_disabled all styles applied and it has all 3 classes conflicting. However having all 3 styles applied is becasue of the js script for datatables.js but not sure how to make it hold only the disabled style when the button itself is disabled instead of having all 3.

Comment: Hopefully you've messed with that file enough to know how to make to where it doesn't load all 3 styles when I just need the disabled because when I open up the firebug in FF it uses the pagination_button style and crosses off the disabled style.

Comment: Elements receive style "rules" from a lot of elements. What style is apllied is calculated with a complicate scoring system. When you have three classes that apply a style to an element (all style applied by classes "scores" ten points), the last style is applied, overriding the previous declarations. CSS is an exact science, but a very difficult one to master, sometimes trial and error is the only way.

Comment: Jsfiddle url does not work any more. Maybe a snippet instead?

Answer (score 1):

Mmm maybe something like:

```
var currentPage = parseInt($(...).text(), 10);
var totalPages = parseInt($(...).text(), 10);
$(".page").removeClass("pagination_button_disabled"); //Enable all initially
if(currentPage == 1){
  $("#first, #previous").addClass("pagination_button_disabled");
}
if(currentPage == totalPages){
  $("#last, #next").addClass("pagination_button_disabled");
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thank you but where is exactly should that be placed? Into that main js file of his or somewhere else?